# Code completion for PHPUnit and Selenium in NetBeans

Tags: netbeans, phpunit

How can I get NetBeans to provide code-completion for PHPUnit classes and methods?

I have already tried downloading from the [PHPUnit GitHub project](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit), but I didn't understand why the directory is different from what's mentioned on the [Selenium documentation](http://www.cs.trincoll.edu/~aalcorn/phpdoc/docbuilder/vmdoc/PHPUnit/PHPUnit_Extensions_SeleniumTestCase.html). I am looking example for the `/test/PHPUnit/Extensions/SeleniumTestCase.php` file.

I have already installed PHPUnit from PEAR, but what I need now is the complete PHPUnit file so I can include it in my IDE (in this case NetBeans).

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Add the PHPUnit directory to NetBeans's PHP global include path. This will provide code completion in NetBeans for all projects.

1. Open **Tools : Options**
2. Switch to the **PHP** tab
3. Click **Add Folder...** next to the **Global Include Path** box
4. Enter `/usr/share/php/PHPUnit` or navigate to where PEAR installed PHPUnit's source files
5. Click **Open**
6. Click **OK**

**Update:** The file defining `PHPUnit_Extensions_SeleniumTestCase` is placed in the same directory as PHPUnit when you install [PHPUnit Selenium](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit-selenium).

For example, `PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase` is stored in

```
/usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Framework/TestCase.php
```

The Selenium test case is stored in

```
/usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Extensions/SeleniumTestCase.php
```

So by placing `/usr/share/php/PHPUnit` into the NetBeans include path, you pick up both. You have to install the extension first, of course.

```
pear install phpunit/PHPUnit_Selenium
```

Comment: I Know how to include PATH PHP Unit, but what i didn't know is where is the `PHPUnit/Extensions/SeleniumTestCase.php` (the file is not included in GitHub file i downloaded) or class named `PHPUnit_Extensions_SeleniumTestCase` which in this case i download the file from GITHUB.

Comment: ty Sir. There is no problem doing this on Windows without pear.
Just download the files somewhere and add the Dir to NB include Paths.

Comment: DAAAAAAAAAAAAAMN...This has been bugging me for YEARS but not enough for me to look it up. I accidentally stumbled upon this :)

Answer (score 2):

Moving away from PEAR...(I'd even uninstall the PEAR version to avoid conflicts first).

1. Download PHPUnit with sources
   https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit and extract somewhere
   semi-permanent `/your-install-path`
2. Add `/your-install-path/phpunit` to your `PATH`s
3. In Netbeans options (Tools > Options on Windows, Netbeans > Preferences on OS X), go to PHP tab..

   a. Under the General tab, Add Folder... and select the `/your-install-path/src/` folder - this will make the auto complete work

   b. Go to Frameworks & Tools tab, PHPUnit, select the `/your-install-path/phpunit` and `/your-install-path/phpunit-skelgen` respectively - this will make PHPUnit tool work within Netbeans
4. In your project settings, right click project name > Settings, Testing category, enable PHPUnit. Optionally go to the Testing > PHPUnit settings panel and make adjustments for your project.

Edit:
When I followed the instructions above, the output window told me I needed to install dependencies using "composer install." These additional steps were needed on my machine (running Netbeans 8.2 on Windows 7).

5. Download Composer and install: https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md
6. Modify `your-install-path/composer.json` by adding the version number between the "description" and "type" keywords like so:

   ```
   "description": "The PHP Unit Testing framework.",
   "version": "5.7.8",
   "type": "library",
   ```
7. Using the command line, type the following (this is a windows machine, for mac or lunix, it should be a little different):

   ```
   cd your-install-path
   composer install
   ```